# Logout issue with site minder in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have implemented the *logout* function in my application which uses site minder for *login*.Every time i logout for the first time its logs me out.If i login again and try to log out it directly logs in without asking credentials.

Can you help me on this. I have used `$cookiestore` to remove the cookies but its doesn't helps. Is there any way to get rid out of it.

Code:-

```
$scope.logoutUser = function() {
         $cookieStore.remove('AWSELB');
         $cookieStore.remove('SMSESSION');
         window.location.href = config['logout_url'];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After calling `$cookieStore.remove`, try to read the value from cookie, it is still there, remove does not work properly, I already faced the same issue.

Finally I decided to use the local storage, really it is easy, better and faster

```
service.logout = function () {
   $localStorage.loggedInUser = null;
    $state.go('login');
};
```

On Login:

```
service.login = function () {
   // validate and get data say user
   $localStorage.loggedInUser = user;
   $state.go('home');
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.My problem is every first time its logs me out.If i  login second time and try to logout it doesn't logs out,  i have to click one more logout.